# If Token is not Present I want to redirect the page to login but its not working. When no token is present or logout i want to redirect the page login

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, web-development-server

**I am Using React Router Dom V6**

Here `if(!localStorage.getItem("token")){ navigate("/login") }`  is not Working

import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const [user,setUser]=useState(null);

  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const getUser=async()=>{                                   **Here i have access the token**
    const res=await axios.get("/auth",{
      headers:{
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      },
    });
    setUser(res.data);
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    getUser();
  },[]);

  const logout=()=>{                     **I have removed the token here**
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    navigate("/login");
  };

  if(!localStorage.getItem("token")){    //HERE IS NOT WORKING
    navigate("/login");
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="m-5">
      <div className="jumbotron">
        <p className="lead">Welcome {user && user.name}</p>
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this in the useEffect method if the token is there then getuser otherwise  navigate to the login page

```js
  useEffect(()=>{
  if(!localStorage.getItem("token")){
    navigate("/login");
  }else{
    getUser();
  }
  },[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add your `if` statement outside of a function, as suggests [this website](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+run+a+code+just+once+in+react). `if` statements can only be used outside of a function for conditional rendering (i.e. when the `if` statement returns something).
When you want to check something only once, you should check it inside of `useEffect`.
For your example, it should be:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getUser()
  if(!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
    navigate("/login");
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks alot buddy it works. But it is now taking lots of time to get the name can you please help me with that

Comment: This may be due to the fact that `getUser()` is an `async` function, and the if statement is not. Meet Majevadiya's solution should work better, because it fetches the user data only if there is no token. Does his solution solve the problem?